# adding security in Struts 2 spring application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, struts2

I am developing an application with spring 3 struts 2 and hibernate. After login only i have to display the pages

It is working fine. when i testing i found the big mistake

that is i copy the url of the page which needs to display only to logged-in user
and paste it in other browser means it is displaying the page without login.

```
 <%
    String userId= (String)session.getAttribute("userId");             
    System.out.println(userId);                        

    if(userId == null || userId.equals("") ){
        response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
    }

%>
```

I have included this for all jsp. I know this is not a best practice. Is any better option available?

How would i overcome this error?

Comment: How you are authenticating users? Some more info like that will be helpful for others to help you.

Comment: How are you authorizing requests?  Does the URL contain any unguessable string?

Comment: We have group of users in user table and have the user name and password for each user. if the user name and password is correct means we allowed to login

Comment: @MikeSamuel. I normally used struts2 and spring 3 and don't have add any authorizing requests. It works as normal struts flow

Comment: Do you use a remember me feature?

Comment: No. i tried in different browsers.

Comment: Why they give down vote without proper comment?

Comment: What do you mean normal Struts flow? How do you check if user is logged in?

Comment: in the loginAction execute method i set the user id in session.

Comment: And where do you check this id? Your question is very vague, improve it.

Comment: It is very ugly do to so on every JSP. If you are using Struts2 create interceptor that checks if user is allowed to see some pages.

Comment: @AleksandrM. Is there any way to using struts and spring

Comment: You mean spring-security? Yes.

Comment: yes. It will resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(userId == null || userId.equals("") ){
    response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
}
```

should probably have a return in there to prevent rendering the page content:

```
if(userId == null || userId.equals("") ){
    response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
    return;
}
```

Nothing in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29) suggests that `sendRedirect` causes abrupt exit or causes the response body to not be shipped to the client.

What is probably happening is that your response contains a redirect header, but also contains the page content which you might not have meant to send.

Answer (score 0):

I am still at education so do know how good is my solution , but i did not crash so hope it is correct

and it is quite similar to @muthu 's code

I had used JPA-eclipselink and Struts2

Action Class

```
String checkLogin = "SELECT user FROM UserEntity user WHERE user.username = :username AND user.password = :password";
Query checkLoginQuery = em.createQuery(checkLogin);
checkLoginQuery.setParameter("username", loginUsername);
checkLoginQuery.setParameter("password", loginPassword);

userEntity = (UserEntity) checkLoginQuery.getSingleResult();

Map sessionMap = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
sessionMap.put("userEntity", userEntity);
```

---

JSP -> all jsp pages have this(bug:affected if session is not killed when browser is not closed )

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<s:if test="%{#session.userEntity == null}">
            <jsp:forward page="login.jsp"/>
</s:if>
```

---

---

Correct me if I am wrong

[Quoting this page](http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=22795)

> Both  and RequestDispatcher.forward() are what I refer to as "server-side" redirects
>
> The response.sendRedirect() is what I call a "client-side" redirect.

so a server side forward looks more safe to me , maybe I am wrong (I am sorry if I am miss interpreting it ,not worked in real life projects yet)